# ZF2 custom view helper not registering

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm new to ZF2 and are trying to create a custom [view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html). In a view called profiles.phtml I do

```
echo $this->MyModuleHelper()->greetings('stack');
```

Which is resulting in

**Fatal error:** Class 'Dashboard\View\Helper\MyModuleHelper' not found in **C:\dashboard\Application\module\Dashboard\Module.php** on line **112**

What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Application/module/Dashboard/Module.php

```
namespace Dashboard;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ViewHelperProviderInterface;

use Dashboard\View\Helper\MyModuleHelper;

class Module implements ViewHelperProviderInterface {
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
        //Some stuff 
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getViewHelperConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'MyModuleHelper' => function ( $sl ) {
                    return new MyModuleHelper();  //Line 112
                }
            ),
        );  
    }
}
```

Application/module/Dashboard/view/Helper/MyModuleHelper.php

```
namespace Dashboard\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class MyModuleHelper extends AbstractHelper   {

    public function __invoke() {
        return $this;
    }

    public function greetings( $userName ) {
        return $this->escapeHtml( sprintf("Hello, %s! ", $userName) ); 
    }
}
```

Side note: I've also tried registering it in module.config.php (instead of Module.php) like

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'MyModuleHelper' => 'Dashboard\View\Helper\MyModuleHelper',
    )
)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried registering it in `module.config.php`? Any errors etc? I recommend this approach over putting it in `Module.php` if it's an invokable class. Also check obvious stuff like is your `module.config.php` being cached?

Comment: @Svengali when doing it from `module.config.php` I get Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::createFromInvokable: failed retrieving "mymodulehelper(alias: MyModuleHelper)" via invokable class "Dashboard\View\Helper\MyModuleHelper"; class does not exist. The reason why I'm going for the first approiach is that I am going to access the service manager and pass a database object to MyModuleHelper.

Comment: That's fine, if it needs the service manager then that's fair enough :) That error makes it sound like it's a trivial problem we're dealing with, however it might be tricky to find. _Triple_ check that your namespaces, class and file names are all correct. Your actual view helper looks fine to me.

Comment: try use :
`use Application\Dashboard\View\Helper\MyModuleHelper;`
// everwhere use Application namespace on start
i check your code and everything work if you use "Application"
BTW
`return $this->escapeHtml( sprintf("Hello, %s! ", $userName) );`
should be
`return $this->vew->escapeHtml( sprintf("Hello, %s! ", $userName) );`

Comment: `Application/module/Dashboard/view/Helper/MyModuleHelper.php` That doesn't look right, it should be `Application/module/Dashboard/src/Dashboard/View/Helper/MyModuleHelper.php`

Comment: @PawełMalisak adding "Application" to "use" will return the same error - but it will make my IDE to loose the connection. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your directory structure is wrong. Please show it. Also, it's good to move the conversation in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I had the directory structure messed up.

I placed my helper in 
`Application/module/Dashboard/view/Helper/MyModuleHelper.php`

When it should have been put in 
`Application/module/Dashboard/src/Dashboard/View/Helper/MyModuleHelper.php`